# checking if gridview is empty using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview

Currently i have the following:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("EMPTY");
}
else
{
    using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"))
    {
        soundPlayer.Play(); // can also use soundPlayer.PlaySync()
    }
}
```

My grid view looks like this:

[image]

But it seems to go to the else statement and make the sound. I need it to NOT make a sound if there is no data in the rows of the gridview.

Comment: how do you populate with data that grid ?

Comment: `BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
                BS.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = BS;`

Comment: ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms or what else? What is the datasource of it?

Comment: WinForms (Windows Application) .net 4

Comment: You also check this when populate gridview.. like this 
DataSet studentsList = students.GetAllStudents(); 
bool empty = IsEmpty(studentsList); 
if(empty) { MessageBox.Show("EMPTY"); } 
else { 
using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav")) 
{ soundPlayer.Play(); // can also use soundPlayer.PlaySync() } }

Comment: Your DataGridView has 1 row with index=NewRowIndex. Number of DataGridViewRow object in DataGridView.Rows collection isn't always equal to number of objects in underlying DataSource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the comment, you have:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = BS;
```

where BS is `BindingSource`, so you can use its [BindingSource.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.count.aspx) property.

So somewhere in the code:

```
var bindingSource = dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource; 
if(bindingSource.Count == 0) {
  MessageBox.Show("EMPTY");
}
```

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Then please accept this as the right answer. Click the tick to turn it green.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Thank you :) Lets give credit where it due. Give those guys the rep they deserve :)

Answer (score 1):

You also check this when populate gridview.. like this

```
DataSet studentsList = students.GetAllStudents(); 
bool empty = IsEmpty(studentsList); 
if(empty) { 
MessageBox.Show("EMPTY"); 
} 
else { 
using (var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"))
{ 
soundPlayer.Play(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `GetCellCount()` to get the cell count. It requires a parameter called `DataGridViewElementStates.Selected`

Example:

```
 if (this.myGridView.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
        {
            //Do sth
        }
        else
        {
            //Show message
        }
```

Advantage is you don't need to run database query to check condition using the mentioned function.
More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcellcount